# How to send multi packets over tcp delphi

Tags: delphi, tcp, record

If I need to send different types of records, how can I determine what 
record type the server is receiving?

```
TRecord1 = packet record
String1: String[10];
String2: String[25];
end;

TRecord2 = packet record
String3: String[30];
MyInt: Integer;
end;
```

I can easily send the record of choice, but how do I let the server know 
which record is being sent?

Comment: Send record type first.

Comment: Send a leading byte, or whatever, that would identify what follows. You can getaway with a tagged variant record though.

Comment: Nope, I doubt that a hypothetical example would help. First you put in a [mcve], then someone might pickup from there.

Comment: Stop burying your details in comment noise. Instead, [edit] your question and add it there, where it can be seen and properly formatted. You can always find the [edit] link to your posts here in the lower-left corner (for questions, just below the tags).

Comment: Not enough details for anyone to answer properly. Please [edit] to add more information, and preferably the relevant code.

Comment: Not enough details please edit your question with WHAT have you tried in a code tags

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251469/should-i-ask-questions-that-have-been-answered-on-other-qa-sites

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply: you can't.

At the end of the day the record is just transferred over TCP as an array of bytes.
The receiving end has no idea which structure it is looking at.
Worse yet, if the receiver and transmitter are running on different platforms, they might not even agree on the byte order!

- You have to "help" the receiver by transmitting a code first that announces what kind of record is coming down the line. Optionally you could even transmit the size of the record (this allows you to skip "alien" structures and/or records you have invented later that the receiver doesn't understand yet - without going off the rails).
- By convention you can choose to make the first field of every record you have unique for the type of record. This way, the receiver can know from the first field which record it is dealing with.

Answer (score -1):

You should serialize entire object to something like JSON and in other side deserialize receive object to proper object.

You can use these open source projects or write your own serializer/deserializer :

- https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject
- https://github.com/krystianbigaj/kblib

Comment: How would that help solve this problem? You answered a different question.